# Javascript Different Behaviour when Executing Function vs Code

Tags: javascript

I'm working on programming a small control panel system, part of which involves some multi-window management. I've written a nice class, and everything works fine, except when I try to close it. For example, I have this function:

```
var topwin = "something";
function closeTop() {
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (links[i].fetch == topwin) {
            links[i].close();
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

When I define the function by pasting it into the console, it works and behaves correctly. But, just being included in window.js along with everything else, it does not work :it misbehaves and closes ALL windows. Idas?

**Edit**: More code

```
this.close = function () {
    $("a[href='"+this.fetch+"']", "#windowlist").css({height: "0px", padding: '0px 20px', margin:'0px'});
    var me = this.me;
    var fetch = this.fetch;
        setTimeout(function() {
            me.remove();
            $("a[href='"+this.fetch+"']", "#windowlist").remove();
            deleteme = fetch;
            sendtotop(links[0].fetch);
            update();
        }, 300);
}
```

-

```
function update () {
    thread = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        if (deleteme==links[i].fetch) {
            links.splice(i, 1);
            deleteme = null;
            i--;
            continue;
        }
        thread += '<li><a href="'+ links[i].fetch +'">'+ links[i].name +'<span>x</span></a></li>';
    }
    $("#windowlist").html(thread);
}
```

Comment: did you try debugging ?

Comment: @GX. Yes, I did. Hence my description of using web inspector an so on. the window's object close() function is not the problem.

Comment: Try to debug it in the browser by adding `console.log(links[i])` in your loop, just before you close().  Then look at the output it generates in the web inspector's console. For some reason, the items in your links array are being considered equal to the topwin, but you haven't provided enough context for us to say why that happens.

Comment: Could you post a little bit more about `links`? I can see it's an array and it's got a `fetch` property and a `close()` method. I'm imagining each element in the `links` array is based the 'nice class' you mentioned and I'm assuming `fetch` is the name of the window in each case, but (apart from the obvious!) what is the `close()` method doing exactly?

Comment: I'll edit my post to include more complete code

Comment: Consider creating a fiddle for such stuff (http://jsfiddle.net/), makes it VERY easy for others to help you.

Comment: Edit: Did some more digging. When I define the function by pasting it into the console, it works and behaves correctly. But, just being included in window.js along with everything else, it does not work. Ideas?

Comment: It's just a hunch/idea but that variable `deleteme` looks suspicious. It doesn't seem to be declared anywhere, so I'm assuming it's global. Not sure why that would mean different behaviour when using the console as opposed to window.js but it might be worth trying to pass `update` as an argument to `this.close` and declare `deleteme` as local but pass it as an argument to `update`... Unfortunately without more code it's hard to say. As suggested before, it'd be good to know more about your `links` class, or about the structure of the programme as a whole.